# AWS Lex integration with Grails 2.4.4

Tags: java, grails-2.4, amazon-lex

I am using Grails 2.4.4 with JAVA 7. I am trying to find out a way to integrate Grails with Amazon Lex, so that i can send and receive text to/from aws-lex api. I am not able to find much on aws documentation. Anybody have any idea regarding this or did anything similar ? Thanks

Comment: Try the [AWS SDK for Java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html) and search for Lex.

Comment: I am using aws-sdk:1.11.11.But did not find a way to make REST call to lex. It seems, lex doesn't support REST calls ?